# How do I smooth out a path

Tags: path

here is a gif that shows what I mean, https://gyazo.com/8eddc89e4b69484d22b8974d49c474fd

I want to make a path for the tractor to follow but the paths are just to rough, even if I extrude 10 times or 100 times, it keeps chopping. im a blender noob :/ but if someone knows an easy way for me to make a smooth path that would be great

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is to increase the curve resolution. Properties > Object Data Properties > Shape > Resolution Preview/Render U and increase the value(s). If that doesn't help, maybe [upload your Blender file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) so others can better see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just increase the resolution of the curve:

[image]

I also see that you are using a NURBS path with several extrusions to form the simple curved road shape. Curves are designed to help artists interpolate between control points so they don't need to manually add dozens or hundreds of them. Try to use as few control points as possible.

I advise you to use bezier curves, as they offer users much more control over the shape. Here is what the road (I assume it is a quarter circle, I might be wrong) would look like. I added a primitive Bezier Circle and deleted the other 3/4ths of it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! Also, I dont have those arrows that shows which direction its going, any reason for that?

Comment: The arrows are the normals. You can display/hide them in the Overlays panel https://i.imgur.com/5xUDBut.png

Comment: @TumpyGFX I am glad to have helped. If this was the answer to the problem you can also mark the solution as accepted by clicking the checkmark below the votes to let others know this worked for you.